# Why mozilla plugins and xulrunner being used by WebKitGTK?

Tags: webkit, media-player, gstreamer, webkitgtk

I've got a simple application using `WebKitGTK 1.6.0` that simply displays a webpage in a window.

When I browse a page using it that contains an Ogg/Theora video and HTML5 video element it appears this simple application is using some mozilla plugins and even xulrunner. Can somebody tell me why this is?

Here is [a list of files open by the program using lsof](http://pastebin.com/YNNZX09p).

I built `WebKitGTK 1.6.0` and most of it's dependencies from source including `gstreamer-0.10` and the `gstreamer plugins`. No where do I recall configuring `WebKitGTK` to using any mozilla plugins or xulrunner.

What might be causing the mozilla plugins, libtotem and xulrunner to be loaded? I provided the link to the files the application is using in hopes that it might provide a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, found the reason. I have FireFox, totem and totem-mozplugin installed on my system. Once I removed totem and totem-mozplugin, `WebKitGTK` used the appropriate Gstreamer plugins to render the video and audio.